# Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app to heroku

Tags: heroku, assets, git-push

Failed to push to heroku not sure why please some one help me I tried many things but nothing works.. it give me error
I did bundle then git add and commit then the get push to heroku

```
 git push heroku master
Counting objects: 132, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (107/107), done.
Writing objects: 100% (108/108), 594.97 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 108 (delta 60), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Rubygems 2.0.14.1 is not threadsafe, so your gems will be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
remote:        Installing rake 11.3.0
remote:        Using i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Using json 1.8.3
remote:        Installing minitest 5.9.1
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Using builder 3.2.2
remote:        Using erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Using rack 1.5.5
remote:        Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
remote:        Installing bcrypt 3.1.11 with native extensions
remote:        Using sass 3.2.19
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Installing execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Using thor 0.19.1
remote:        Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Using hike 1.2.3
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.12.1
remote:        Installing pg 0.19.0 with native extensions
remote:        Using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Using tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
remote:        Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
remote:        Installing turbolinks-source 5.0.0
remote:        Installing rdoc 4.2.2
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Using rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Using warden 1.2.6
remote:        Installing mime-types 3.1
remote:        Using bootstrap-sass 3.2.0.2
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing uglifier 3.0.2
remote:        Using sprockets 2.12.4
remote:        Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Installing turbolinks 5.0.1
remote:        Installing sdoc 0.4.2
remote:        Using activesupport 4.1.10
remote:        Installing mail 2.6.4
remote:        Using actionview 4.1.10
remote:        Using activemodel 4.1.10
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.6.0
remote:        Using actionpack 4.1.10
remote:        Using activerecord 4.1.10
remote:        Using actionmailer 4.1.10
remote:        Using railties 4.1.10
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 2.3.3
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
remote:        Using responders 1.1.2
remote:        Using jquery-rails 3.1.4
remote:        Using jquery-ui-rails 5.0.5
remote:        Using rails 4.1.10
remote:        Using sass-rails 4.0.5
remote:        Installing devise 4.2.0
remote:        Gem::InstallError: devise requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0.
remote:        An error occurred while installing devise (4.2.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install devise -v '4.2.0'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:        Bundler Output: Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Rubygems 2.0.14.1 is not threadsafe, so your gems will be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
remote:        Installing rake 11.3.0
remote:        Using i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Using json 1.8.3
remote:        Installing minitest 5.9.1
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Using builder 3.2.2
remote:        Using erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Using rack 1.5.5
remote:        Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
remote:        Installing bcrypt 3.1.11 with native extensions
remote:        Using sass 3.2.19
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Installing execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Using thor 0.19.1
remote:        Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Using hike 1.2.3
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.12.1
remote:        Installing pg 0.19.0 with native extensions
remote:        Using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Using tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
remote:        Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
remote:        Installing turbolinks-source 5.0.0
remote:        Installing rdoc 4.2.2
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Using rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Using warden 1.2.6
remote:        Installing mime-types 3.1
remote:        Using bootstrap-sass 3.2.0.2
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing uglifier 3.0.2
remote:        Using sprockets 2.12.4
remote:        Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Installing turbolinks 5.0.1
remote:        Installing sdoc 0.4.2
remote:        Using activesupport 4.1.10
remote:        Installing mail 2.6.4
remote:        Using actionview 4.1.10
remote:        Using activemodel 4.1.10
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.6.0
remote:        Using actionpack 4.1.10
remote:        Using activerecord 4.1.10
remote:        Using actionmailer 4.1.10
remote:        Using railties 4.1.10
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 2.3.3
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
remote:        Using responders 1.1.2
remote:        Using jquery-rails 3.1.4
remote:        Using jquery-ui-rails 5.0.5
remote:        Using rails 4.1.10
remote:        Using sass-rails 4.0.5
remote:        Installing devise 4.2.0
remote:        
remote:        Gem::InstallError: devise requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0.
remote:        An error occurred while installing devise (4.2.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install devise -v '4.2.0'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to nour-abu-khajil.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/nour-abu-khajil.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/nour-abu-khajil.git'
```

Here is in the gemfile
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.10'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development

gem "rails_12factor", group: :production 
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'

group :assets do
  gem "jquery-ui-rails"
end

gem "devise"
```

So what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a problem related to the ruby version Heroku is using. You could try [setting the ruby version so Heroku uses](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions) the same one as you use locally.

Comment: Thank you :) I add ruby "2.1.2" in the gemfile